# How to interpret the syntax of \newcommand in latex in comparison with the command it defines

Tags: latex

I am new to Latex, and the question is just for curiosity. I wonder why the `\newcommand` command in latex has a different syntax than other commands?

The syntax of `\newcommand` is

```
\newcommand{<arg>}[<options>][<options>]{<arg>}
```

while the syntax for user-defined commands (or macros?) are like

```
\<command>[<options>]{<arg>}{<arg>}
```

I did not find any method for a user to define a command whose use model is something like: (i.e. [] appears after {})

```
\<command>{<args>}[<options>]{<args>}
```

So how do we differentiate the `\newcommand` command with other user-defined commands? Call them preserved command? Some commands whose syntax not definable by the user?

Comment: Even as a user one can define commands that have the mandatory arguments before the optional arguments. The easiest way is something like `\DeclareDocumentCommand`, see the documentation of the `xparse` package for more details

Comment: The LaTeX \newcommand is itself build with a more general TeX macro that can create new macros and that is called  '\def'. \def allows to create any kind of macros, including with different optional arguments at any position, but it can be very tricky to do that. \newcommand gives a much simpler way to define macros with an optional argument, but there are some limitations. It is also safer as it prevents redefining vital commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not really have a different syntax, it's just defined in a way that gobbles its arguments differently. Here are some examples to highlight this...

Consider

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\firstcmd}[1]{first: #1}
\newcommand{\secondcmd}[2][opt2]{second: #1/#2}
\newcommand{\thirdcmd}[1]{third: #1 \fourthcmd}
\newcommand{\fourthcmd}[2][opt4]{fourth: #1/#2}

\begin{document}

\firstcmd{abc}

\secondcmd{def}

\secondcmd[abc]{def}

\thirdcmd{ghi}{jkl}

\thirdcmd{ghi}[jkl]{mno}

\fourthcmd{mno}

\fourthcmd[mno]{pqr}

\end{document}
```

`\firstcmd`, `\secondcmd` and `\fourthcmd` are all defined in the usual way. `\firstcmd` takes a single, mandatory argument, while `\secondcmd` and `\fourthcmd` each take a single optional argument followed by a mandatory argument. That is, they have the form `\<cmd>[.]{..}`.

`\thirdcmd` is defined to take a single, mandatory argument, but is nested with `\fourthcmd`. So, while it's definition seems to require one argument, nesting it causes it's use to resemble something that could take two or three arguments, depending on whether you supply an optional argument or not.

[image]

In this way, any configuration of optional/mandatory argument sequence is possible. `\newcommand` is defined in a similar way. Regardless, you should consider usability when defining commands that may have optional arguments scattered throughout its argument sequence. For example, let's say you defined `\mycmd{.}[..][...]{....}`, hoping to allow two optional arguments next each other. If the end-user specifies

```
\mycmd{.}[..]{....}
```

the execution (picking up appropriate arguments in the way they're intended) would happen as expected. However, if the end-user specifies

```
\mycmd{.}[...]{....}
```

hoping to skip the second optional argument `[..]`, the execution will most certainly fail (or not happen as expected), since there's no distinction which optional argument is being left out/supplied.

A general approach to avoiding this confusion would be to use a key-valued approach. For example, define a command with a single optional argument that takes a key-value list:

```
\mycmd[key1=value, key2=value, ...]{<arg>}{...}
```

This will clearly distinguish what is being passed as optional content, and allow you to specify default values for keys that are not present (see the [`keyval`](//ctan.org/pkg/keyval) or [`xkeyval`](//ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval) packages).

---

Regardless, other packages also provide an easier means to intermix optional and mandatory arguments, if that's what you're after. Here's on example using [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{o m O{opt2} m}{%
  mycmd:
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {#1}
    {no opt1}%
  /#2/#3/#4%
}

\begin{document}

\mycmd{abc}{def}

\mycmd[abc]{def}{ghi}

\mycmd{abc}[def]{ghi}

\mycmd[abc]{def}[ghi]{jkl}

\end{document}
```